# Extract multi-line entries while reading through a log file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7.5 to read the Warnings from a log file and append it to a list. Then use this list to send an email.

**Problem:** The output getting generated by the code doesn't contain multi-line error message. It just logs till `.[`. However, I need to log the whole error so that it can be sent via email. Below mentioned is the code snippet, log file, output generated by the code and expected output.

**Python code:**

```
import arcpy, os
recLogPath = "D:/something/log.txt"

conflictMsgList = []

with open(recLogPath) as logFile:
  for line in logFile:
    if "Warning:" in line:
        print(line)


print(conflictMsgList)
```

**Log file format:**

```
[06/05/2020 15:15:33] Reconciling version "SD\EL".Elliot_Menzies with sde.DEFAULT.

[06/05/2020 15:15:40] Warning: Conflicts found reconciling version "SD\EL".E_M.

[06/05/2020 15:15:40] 3 of 9 versions finished.

[06/05/2020 15:15:40] Reconciling version "SD\ME".K_M with sde.DEFAULT.

[06/05/2020 15:16:16] Warning: Error reconciling version "SD\ME".K_M.[
    The geometry corresponding to an edge element may not be zero length. [class = srw.SRW.ww_pipe, oid = 23]
    Field is not editable.
    Lock request conflicts with an established lock [Lock request conflicts with an established lock[
SR]]
```

**Output generated:**

```
[06/05/2020 13:36:36] Warning: Conflicts found reconciling version "SD\EL".E_M.

[06/05/2020 13:36:54] Warning: Error reconciling version "SD\ME".K_M.[
```

**Expected output which I need:**

```
[06/05/2020 13:36:36] Warning: Conflicts found reconciling version "SD\EL".E_M.

[06/05/2020 15:16:16] Warning: Error reconciling version "SD\ME".K_M.[
    The geometry corresponding to an edge element may not be zero length. [class = srw.SRW.ww_pipe, oid = 23]
    Field is not editable.
    Lock request conflicts with an established lock [Lock request conflicts with an established lock[
SR]]
```

Comment: You need a parser where you can keep track of the number of open `[ ]` blocks.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm new to Python, if you could please share the code snippet, it would be great!

Comment: I don't have such a "snippet". I suspect that this is no trivial task and cannot be handled by only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

It assumes that 'inner log' lines don't start on newline with '['.

```
def get_logs(logfilename):
    with open(logfilename) as logFile:
        loglines = logFile.readlines()

    logs = []
    for line in loglines:
        if line.startswith('['):
            logs.append(line)
        else:
            logs[-1] += line
    return logs

logs = get_logs(recLogPath)
for log in logs:
    if 'Warning:' in log:
        print(log)
```